# Fill the blanks taking into consideration the first date

Tags: r, tidyr

I want to fill a variable with dates taking into consideration an already existing date. I have the first date for each client, however, I need to make +1 month for the next observations.

The order of the data comes from the variable `Year`. The first value (`NO_CREDITO==118510`,`Year` == 0.08, `Starting_date` == 2017-03-14) has the starting date. What I want is to get for the next value (`Year` == 0.17) the `Starting_date + 1 month` (2017-04-14) and so on until the last one (the amount of times is given by the variable `Amount of Payments`.

This should be done in a `group_by` since my real data has many loans.

Here is some sample data:

```
prestamos <- structure(list(Year = c(0.08, 0.17, 0.25, 0.33, 0.42, 0.5, 0.58, 
0.67, 0.75, 0.83, 0.92, 1, 1.08, 1.17, 1.25, 1.33, 1.42, 1.5, 
1.58, 1.67, 1.75, 1.83, 1.92, 2, 2.08, 2.17, 2.25, 2.33, 2.42, 
2.5, 2.58, 2.67, 2.75, 2.83, 2.92, 3, 3.08, 3.17, 3.25, 3.33, 
3.42, 3.5, 3.58, 3.67, 3.75, 3.83, 3.92, 4, 0.08, 0.17, 0.25, 
0.33, 0.42, 0.5, 0.58, 0.67, 0.75, 0.83, 0.92, 1, 1.08, 1.17, 
1.25, 1.33, 1.42, 1.5, 1.58, 1.67, 1.75, 1.83, 1.92, 2, 2.08, 
2.17, 2.25, 2.33, 2.42, 2.5, 2.58, 2.67, 2.75, 2.83, 2.92, 3), 
    Payment = c(23655.53, 23655.53, 23655.53, 23655.53, 23655.53, 
    23655.53, 23655.53, 23655.53, 23655.53, 23655.53, 23655.53, 
    23655.53, 23655.53, 23655.53, 23655.53, 23655.53, 23655.53, 
    23655.53, 23655.53, 23655.53, 23655.53, 23655.53, 23655.53, 
    23655.53, 23655.53, 23655.53, 23655.53, 23655.53, 23655.53, 
    23655.53, 23655.53, 23655.53, 23655.53, 23655.53, 23655.53, 
    23655.53, 23655.53, 23655.53, 23655.53, 23655.53, 23655.53, 
    23655.53, 23655.53, 23655.53, 23655.53, 23655.53, 23655.53, 
    23655.53, 5808.78, 5808.78, 5808.78, 5808.78, 5808.78, 5808.78, 
    5808.78, 5808.78, 5808.78, 5808.78, 5808.78, 5808.78, 5808.78, 
    5808.78, 5808.78, 5808.78, 5808.78, 5808.78, 5808.78, 5808.78, 
    5808.78, 5808.78, 5808.78, 5808.78, 5808.78, 5808.78, 5808.78, 
    5808.78, 5808.78, 5808.78, 5808.78, 5808.78, 5808.78, 5808.78, 
    5808.78, 5808.78), `Interest Paid` = c(12247.58, 12072.93, 
    11895.6, 11715.57, 11532.77, 11347.18, 11158.74, 10967.42, 
    10773.18, 10575.95, 10375.71, 10172.41, 9965.99, 9756.41, 
    9543.62, 9327.57, 9108.22, 8885.51, 8659.39, 8429.8, 8196.71, 
    7960.04, 7719.75, 7475.78, 7228.08, 6976.58, 6721.24, 6461.98, 
    6198.76, 5931.5, 5660.16, 5384.66, 5104.94, 4820.94, 4532.59, 
    4239.83, 3942.59, 3640.79, 3334.38, 3023.27, 2707.4, 2386.7, 
    2061.08, 1730.48, 1394.82, 1054.02, 708.01, 356.69, 2529.88, 
    2477.37, 2424.03, 2369.84, 2314.77, 2258.83, 2201.98, 2144.23, 
    2085.56, 2025.94, 1965.37, 1903.83, 1841.31, 1777.78, 1713.23, 
    1647.66, 1581.03, 1513.34, 1444.56, 1374.68, 1303.68, 1231.54, 
    1158.25, 1083.79, 1008.14, 931.27, 853.17, 773.82, 693.2, 
    611.29, 528.07, 443.52, 357.61, 270.33, 181.64, 91.54), `Principal Paid` = c(11407.95, 
    11582.6, 11759.92, 11939.96, 12122.76, 12308.35, 12496.78, 
    12688.1, 12882.35, 13079.57, 13279.82, 13483.12, 13689.54, 
    13899.12, 14111.91, 14327.96, 14547.31, 14770.02, 14996.14, 
    15225.72, 15458.82, 15695.49, 15935.78, 16179.75, 16427.45, 
    16678.95, 16934.29, 17193.55, 17456.77, 17724.02, 17995.37, 
    18270.87, 18550.59, 18834.59, 19122.93, 19415.7, 19712.94, 
    20014.73, 20321.15, 20632.26, 20948.12, 21268.83, 21594.44, 
    21925.04, 22260.7, 22601.5, 22947.52, 23298.83, 3278.9, 3331.41, 
    3384.75, 3438.94, 3494.01, 3549.95, 3606.8, 3664.55, 3723.22, 
    3782.84, 3843.41, 3904.95, 3967.47, 4031, 4095.55, 4161.12, 
    4227.75, 4295.44, 4364.22, 4434.1, 4505.1, 4577.24, 4650.53, 
    4724.99, 4800.64, 4877.51, 4955.61, 5034.96, 5115.58, 5197.49, 
    5280.71, 5365.26, 5451.17, 5538.45, 5627.14, 5717.24), Balance = c(788592.05, 
    777009.45, 765249.52, 753309.56, 741186.8, 728878.45, 716381.67, 
    703693.57, 690811.21, 677731.64, 664451.83, 650968.7, 637279.16, 
    623380.04, 609268.13, 594940.18, 580392.87, 565622.85, 550626.71, 
    535400.98, 519942.16, 504246.67, 488310.89, 472131.15, 455703.7, 
    439024.75, 422090.46, 404896.92, 387440.15, 369716.12, 351720.75, 
    333449.88, 314899.3, 296064.71, 276941.78, 257526.08, 237813.14, 
    217798.41, 197477.26, 176845, 155896.88, 134628.05, 113033.61, 
    91108.56, 68847.86, 46246.36, 23298.83, 0, 154721.1, 151389.69, 
    148004.94, 144566, 141071.99, 137522.03, 133915.24, 130250.69, 
    126527.47, 122744.63, 118901.22, 114996.27, 111028.8, 106997.79, 
    102902.25, 98741.13, 94513.38, 90217.93, 85853.71, 81419.61, 
    76914.51, 72337.27, 67686.75, 62961.76, 58161.11, 53283.6, 
    48327.99, 43293.03, 38177.46, 32979.97, 27699.26, 22334, 
    16882.83, 11344.37, 5717.24, 0), NO_CREDITO = c("118510", 
    "118510", "118510", "118510", "118510", "118510", "118510", 
    "118510", "118510", "118510", "118510", "118510", "118510", 
    "118510", "118510", "118510", "118510", "118510", "118510", 
    "118510", "118510", "118510", "118510", "118510", "118510", 
    "118510", "118510", "118510", "118510", "118510", "118510", 
    "118510", "118510", "118510", "118510", "118510", "118510", 
    "118510", "118510", "118510", "118510", "118510", "118510", 
    "118510", "118510", "118510", "118510", "118510", "118511", 
    "118511", "118511", "118511", "118511", "118511", "118511", 
    "118511", "118511", "118511", "118511", "118511", "118511", 
    "118511", "118511", "118511", "118511", "118511", "118511", 
    "118511", "118511", "118511", "118511", "118511", "118511", 
    "118511", "118511", "118511", "118511", "118511", "118511", 
    "118511", "118511", "118511", "118511", "118511"), Starting_date = structure(c(17239, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 17239, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), Amount_of_Payments = c(48L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 36L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -84L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you better describe what calculation you're looking to do? Provide a formula to execute and describe how you want it executed, or something of the sort.

Comment: Given an amount, start date, interest rate and amount of years of the loan, you can get the interest and capital that you will be paying each month. I want to get a table that gives me that for each loan. I'll upload the formula right now.

Comment: So what you're looking to do is `capital = amount * (interest / 100) / months`? If so I don't understand the numbers in `Loan_length` - what is `0.493, 0.997`? Parts of a month or of a year?

Comment: loan length is the length in years, and all of them are paid in a monthly basis

Comment: I've put an answer but this makes no sense. `5.002739` years is essentially 5 years + less than a day, this can't be something the bank made you sign. Please make sure your numbers are what you think they are.

Answer (score 0):

If several numeric vectors are of the same length, you can make calculations on them like you would on regular numbers.

Now, assuming`Loan_length` is in years, you gotta convert them into months, then divide the total loan amount by number of months, therefore:

```r
Capital <- (df$Amount * (1 + df$Interest_rate / 100)) / (df$Loan_lenght * 12)
```

Likewise, in order to see the end-of-loan date, you add the corresponding amounts of time to the starting dates.

```r
library(lubridate)
End <- df$Starting_date
month(End) <- month(End) + df$Loan_length * 12
```

Here, since all the columns in `df` are of length `6`, `Capital` too is of length `6`, with every entry corresponding to its `ID` value.

```r
cbind(df$ID, Capital, df$Starting_date, End)
```

Comment: I would need to use the date in order to know when which payment will be done, and also calculate the interest. That's why im trying to get it in a table.

Comment: I have edited the answer to also reflect loan end date.